# Book on stochastic processes

Tags: stochastic-processes, gaussian-process, brownian-motion

What is good applied book on stochastic processes? Specifically, a book that focuses on Wiener process and Brownian motion.

PS: Preferably free

Answer (score 2):

You can have a look on:

[Ross, Sheldon M. Introduction to probability models. Academic press, 2010.](https://books.google.com.bd/books?id=0yDAZf1TfJEC&printsec=frontcover&dq=Introduction%20to%20probability%20models&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=Introduction%20to%20probability%20models&f=false) Chapter 10 of the book is "Brownian Motion and Stationary Processes". The PDF of the book is also available in online.

Answer (score 1):

Someone should probably mention Karlin and Taylor's [First Course in Stochastic Processes](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0123985528) although this is more theoretical.

Comment: You just did.  I think it is good for Brownian Motion but it is hard to find a good book on Brownian Motion that is also applied and vice versa.

Comment: The OP doesn't ask for much.  He wants it to be free.  Another old one that I like from the 1970s  Is Hoel, Port and Stone.